# Creating P4Server vs. Server using p4 api .NET

Tags: c#, .net, api, perforce, p4api.net

My end goal is to create a perforce server in which I can log in, create a workspace, and checkin/checkout.  I am going through the p4 api and trying to figure out how to do this, and I am unsure on how to make the perforce server.  There is a Server class, which seems to be the right thing to use since it allows me to create a Connection class.  On the other hand, looking down the road it seems I will be wanting to use P4Command and that takes a P4Server as an argument.  Any guidance about what steps to take is much appreciated!  Here the snippet I am looking at right now.  Are my two servers completely separate?

```
ServerAddress adr = new ServerAddress(uri);
Server server = new Server(adr);
P4Server p4server = new P4Server(uri, user1, password, ws_client);
Repository rep = new Repository(server);
Connection con = rep.Connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create your own Perforce server. The P4API.NET library is not for creating servers, but for connecting to existing Perforce servers.

The API itself seems somewhat convoluted and confusing to me, what with those Server and P4Server classes.